# How to mount file system at u-boot stage without using kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, u-boot, usb-drive

I am beginner to u-boot programming. I would like to load file system of any type and same file system is supposed to mount on usb host machine using ums command in u-boot(as a usb mass storage).

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Pritam

Comment: Not clear what you want. In any case you may consider U-Boot as a simplified Linux kernel + custom set of commands. If it would have driver for hardware it would work in the same way.

Comment: I would like use ram as a usb mass storage device at u-boot stage. So i thought of using some filesystem on u-boot to allow host PC mount.

Comment: You need to look for USB device mode support and gadget driver for your board.

Comment: Yes, its already available (by UMS u-boot command) but with sdcard. I would like xfer data using ram location (not using mmc).